# Is it possible to add nested submodules in the root repo in git?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to make submodule in my repo:

```
Root /
\--- /A (submodule)
```

But also I want to nest another submodule, also in root:

```
Root /
\--- /A (submodule)
 \-- /A/B (another submodule)
```

And I can't add `B` as submodule to `A`, since `A` is a third-party repo.

#### The real-life example.

`llvm` + `clang` trees: I want to include both repos, but `clang` must be checked-out inside `llvm` tree.

Answer (score 1):

No, you would have to:

- add `B` as a submodule of `Root`
- make a symlink ([even on Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)) from `Root/A/B` to `Root/B`.
  That symlink remains private, and isn't added to the (thirdparty) repo `A`.